# How to change the font color of specific words in CSS?

Tags: html, css, fonts, colors

Giving a structure similar to

adjoasdouhaosdh  asdj oaushdo hello

i apologize for the random words, hello

I guess my question would be is there an easier way to make the 'hello's a different color? Sorry if this is confusing

Comment: Please show what you have so far

Comment: I don't really have code right now, and my question wasn't posted the way I wanted it to..but giving a div id, with a lot of <p>'s, how do I alter specific words in collections of strings

Answer (score 2):

HTML

```
<p>adjoasdouhaosdh asdj oaushdo <span>hello</span></p>

<p>i apologize for the random words, <span>hello</span></p>
```

CSS

```
p > span { 
    color: red;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/uq6rswpk/

---

In reference to your comment asking how to select a `<p>` element among a group of `<p>` siblings, you can use the [`:nth-child` pseudo-class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3Anth-child).

```
p:nth-child(2) { ... }
```

Comment: @user201535 Yes `<span>` or any of these --http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_formatting.asp depending on what your trying to do

Comment: Is there a way to do this without altering the original html file?

Comment: With CSS you can't target content within an element. You can target an element, an attribute, and attribute values.

Comment: @Michael_B So you can style a text input like a regular div using appearance: none, then make it uneditable by adding the 'disabled' option, and then you can use css to target the content as the content inside the input is an attribute (value="...").
haha, dirty hack

Comment: I guess there's always some way, as convoluted as it may be, to get around the rules.

Answer (score 1):

So you don't want to wrap tags around the 'hello's manually. There is no way then to do this in css. The only way then is to use javascript to search for these words and wrap them inside tags.

But I would recommend to do this on the server side instead of client side, so in a preprocessing function

Comment: Okay that's fine, but then let's say in a given <div> that has multiple <p>'s, how do we reference a specific <p>. Like if we wanted to get the second <p> block?